# MS Access display query results on form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a simple Clients table and made a form to enter all the fields. I also have a query called "Balances" which does some math and calculates the balance on each clients account. What I want to do now is get a particular Client's balance to show on the form when their record is open.

I tried making a text box with the control source = `[Balances].[Balance]` but it gives me `#Name?` when I view the form. The names are definitely correct, but I'm not sure if this is even the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do a `DLookup()`, in which case the Control Source of your "Balance" text box would be something like

```
=DLookup("Balance", "Balances", "ClientID=" & [ClientID])
```

Experiment with that and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Bingo! It's funny to me how Access over simplifies some things and over complicates others O_o